# Check project for use of code introduced in Java 7

Tags: eclipse, maven, java

On my development machine, I have JDK 1.7 installed, but we are packaging software for use with Java 1.5 and 1.6.  It's easy to set the `-source` and `-target` options so that the **syntax** is forced to be a particular version, and the **output class** is interpretable by a particular VM.  But there are other version-isms that are biting me, like the 2-argument constructor `AssertionError(String, Throwable)` and various other subtle changes.

The one solution I know of is to install every different JDK (1.5, 1.6, 1.7) so that Eclipse can exactly match the execution environment for me.  Is there any other way to detect these problems?  Bonus points if it's an Eclipse or Maven tool.

Comment: Honestly, the "right" way to do this is probably to make _all_ of your code compatible with the lowest common denominator.

Comment: I remember once I had set code level to 1.5 for a project and eclipse was using 1.6 to compile against. I accidentally used String.isEmpty() (introduced in 1.6) in my code and it went unnoticed until the client actually deployed it and ran it. So, don't take chances, make sure you test with right platform. By setting Source and Target level, you cannot be sure that some API introduced in later version is not used.

Comment: You could set the boot class path when compiling but that would still require the respective JDK installed. So installing the different JDKs and running your build with these is still the easiest way. As you figured, Eclipse does this for you, so it should be easy to use.

Comment: Yeah, you folks are probably right.  It's only a pain because I don't have root, so I have to get someone else to update all N Java installations whenever there's an update, but it's the only way to really be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the Codehaus [anmial-sniffer maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/)?  I haven't had reason to try it yet, but thought it looked interesting.

Answer (score 0):

does [this tool](http://code.google.com/p/versioncheck/) help? It's command line, I have seen people using it to detect java7 being used.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only checks for the classes being interpretable by a particular VM.  If you tell `javac -target 1.5`, it will happily create output that a 1.5 VM can understand, but which uses 1.7 libraries that aren't available.